# Rails 4 Date object is not responding to Date methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

In my project, a `course` has a `start_date` and a `finish_date`. Both `start_date` and `finish_date` are Date objects. i.e `some_course.start_date.is_a?(Date)` => true.

In my view, I am trying to print out `start_date` values by doing a loop

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <%= course.start_date %>
<% end %>
```

There is no problem up to this point. However, when I try to use any Date methods such as `.month`, `.to_formatted_s`, I get an error. For instance: undefined method `month' for nil:NilClass

Again, if I try to print out, in my view, `course.start_date.is_a?(Date)`, I see `true`.

Why is the `course.start_date` not responding to Date methods? In particular, I want to use `.to_formatted_s` to print it in a different format.

Comment: If you use `@courses.first`, what do you get? Most likely you don't have any data in the DB, and so you get `nil`.

Comment: @Vucko When I do `<%= @courses.first %>` in my view, I get `#<Course:0x007feb95ce7718>`. And in the console, when I run `Course.count`, I get 4. So, I do not think the data is empty.

Comment: And if you use `<%= @courses.first.start_date %>`, what do you get?

Comment: @Vucko I get a date object, `2014-06-18`

Comment: Maybe you are not loading ActiveSupport for some reason?

Comment: Try loading Active Support Date explicitly http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#how-to-load-core-extensions

Comment: @MikeC : try my answer and let me know what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the course object doesn't have start_date, try putting

```
course.try(:start_date)
```

or

```
course.start_date rescue nil
```

Hope this should help..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran it for all my four courses, but  all of them seem to have start_date. I also checked in the console.

Comment: <%= course.try(:start_date) %> or                                <%= course.start_date rescue nil %>   with this u should not get that error

Comment: Now, I feel very silly. Similar to what you suggested, one of my objects had no start_date. I will make it a habit to check presence of all data thoroughly in the future.